# Modest sized DB with 320 second SELECT

Tags: performance, postgresql-performance

I noticed that one of my Hibernate JPA `SELECT`s against my Heroku PG 10.4 instance is taking a  loooog time to complete as [this `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` shows](https://explain.depesz.com/s/r2GU). The database is 591MB running in PG 10.4 on Heroku with the following row counts and index use:

```
    relname     | percent_of_times_index_used | rows_in_table  
----------------+-----------------------------+---------------
fm_order       | 99                          |       2233237
fm_grant       | Insufficient data           |        204282
fm_trader      | 5                           |         89037
fm_capital     | 99                          |         84267
fm_session     | 99                          |          7182
fm_person      | 99                          |          4365
fm_allocation  | 96                          |          4286
fm_approval    | Insufficient data           |           920
fm_market      | 97                          |           583
fm_account     | 93                          |           451
fm_marketplace | 22                          |           275
```

and the offending JPA JPQL is:

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE                                "
     + "       o.type                  = 'LIMIT'                   "
     + "   AND o.session.original      = :originalSessionId        "
     + "   AND ( (                                                 "
     + "         o.consumer IS NULL                                "
     + "    ) OR (                                                 "
     + "         o.consumer IS NOT NULL                            "
     + "     AND o.consumer > 0                                    "
     + "     AND EXISTS (                                          "
     + "       SELECT 1 FROM Order oo WHERE                        "
     + "             oo.id                    = o.consumer         "
     + "         AND oo.session.original      = :originalSessionId "
     + "         AND oo.type                  = 'LIMIT'            "
     + "         AND oo.owner                != o.owner            "
     + "     )                                                     "
     + "   )                                                       "
     + " )                                                         "
     + " ORDER BY o.lastModifiedDate DESC                          ")
```

which Hibernate turns into:

```
SELECT order0_.id                 AS id1_7_,
       order0_.created_by         AS created_2_7_,
       order0_.created_date       AS created_3_7_,
       order0_.last_modified_by   AS last_mod4_7_,
       order0_.last_modified_date AS last_mod5_7_,
       order0_.consumer           AS consumer6_7_,
       order0_.market_id          AS market_14_7_,
       order0_.original           AS original7_7_,
       order0_.owner_id           AS owner_i15_7_,
       order0_.owner_target       AS owner_ta8_7_,
       order0_.price              AS price9_7_,
       order0_.session_id         AS session16_7_,
       order0_.side               AS side10_7_,
       order0_.supplier           AS supplie11_7_,
       order0_.type               AS type12_7_,
       order0_.units              AS units13_7_
FROM   fm_order order0_
       CROSS JOIN fm_session session1_
WHERE  order0_.session_id = session1_.id
       AND order0_.type = 'LIMIT'
       AND session1_.original = 7569
       AND ( order0_.consumer IS NULL
              OR ( order0_.consumer IS NOT NULL )
                 AND order0_.consumer > 0
                 AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 1
                               FROM   fm_order order2_
                                      CROSS JOIN fm_session session3_
                               WHERE  order2_.session_id = session3_.id
                                      AND order2_.id = order0_.consumer
                                      AND session3_.original = 7569
                                      AND order2_.type = 'LIMIT'
                                      AND
                     order2_.owner_id <> order0_.owner_id) ) )
ORDER  BY order0_.last_modified_date DESC;
```

Any ideas how I turn this 320S disaster around?

Answer (score 0):

Statistics were not up-to-date; executed `ANALYZE` and dropped the redundant:

```
 + "         o.consumer IS NOT NULL               "
```

which [improved performance 100x](https://explain.depesz.com/s/vGVo).